# Horizontally aligning child elements in a wrap panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML in my window:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
    </WrapPanel.Resources>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Yellow"/>
    <Rectangle Height="150" Width="150" Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Blue"/>
    <Rectangle Height="250" Width="250" Fill="Purple"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Which produces the following UI in the designer:
[image: Current layout]

What I'm looking for is a way to 'horizontally align' the child elements in the wrap panel, so that the window would look something like this:
[image: Desired layout]

Is there any way to achieve this in a wrap panel or do I need to consider using other controls or writing a custom control?

This image additionally illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more about the constraints of the desired layout? The red rectangle does not seem to be "horizontally aligned" in the same manner as others so it's not entirely clear what are you after. To achieve just the image you've presented a margin for the yellow rectangle would suffice, but I'm guessing you need something less hand-crafted.

Comment: I'm just testing something for a data entry screen where I'm trying to align each 'group' of controls in a table like layout without having each control staggered. In my actual applications I'd be replacing the rectangles with stackpanels/grids. The rectangles are just for demonstration.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with rectangles. What I don't get is why the red rectangle overlaps horizontally with the purple one, but the yellow one is moved to the right? Is it that the first elements in each (here: red and purple) row are left-aligned, and next elements (here: yellow and none) are not allowed to overlap horizontally?

Comment: Does the third image I added help? I'm basically looking for something that behaves like a grid control without having to explicitly specify the amount of rows or columns that I need.

Comment: Yes, thanks, now it's clear :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a few different techniques, you may be able to get to where you want to be. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242787/1439998) shows how to define responsive column widths:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

If that isn't enough, you could go down the path of having a custom control that uses a grid layout and repositions which column/row each child control is currently in, and on a control or window resize event, redo the layout positioning of what is where based upon columns / pixel calculations.

**UPDATE:**

For a custom control, you could try something similar to this:

public class CustomLayout : Control
   {
      private List children;

```
  public CustomLayout()
  {
      children = new List<Control>();      
  }

  public void AddChild(Control childToAdd)
  {
      children.Add(childToAdd);
      // TODO: Determine if new layout is needed.
  }

  public void RemoveChild(Control childToRemove)
  {
      children.Remove(childToRemove);
      // TODO: Determine if new layout is needed.
  }

  // Call to update the layout.
  private void PerformLayout(int columns, int rows)
  {
     Grid layoutGrid = new Grid();
     // TODO: Programmatically build grid layout.
     RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
     row.Height = 100;
     layoutGrid.Rows.Add(row);

     // Methods for layout:
     // Grid.SetRow(rowID, childControl);
     // Grid.SetColumn(columnID, childControl);


     // Note: This may produce some flashing on resize, so there may be better ways to remove/add the grid such as redoing rows and columns instead.
     Controls.Clear();
     Controls.Add(layoutGrid);
  }

  // Should be called when the window or parent resizes. I can't remember the events in question.
  public void OnResize()
  {
     int columns;
     int rows;
     // TODO: Calculate columns/rows
     PerformLayout(columns, rows);
  }
```

}

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction. Please keep in mind that this is pseudo code and may not fully compile.

Comment: I think a custom control might be needed in this case.

Comment: It will give you the most control, but will also take some time to get the correct implementation.

Comment: Are there any questions on SO that explain how to go about making a control with the behaviour I need?

Comment: I'll try to post a pseudo code update for you on my answer to get you started.

Comment: That's great. I'll have a look at this later on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is a Grid with rows and columns.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,10,10,10"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Rectangle Height="200" Width="200" Fill="Yellow" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Height="150" Width="150" Fill="Green"  Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Blue"  Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Rectangle Height="250" Width="250" Fill="Purple" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

This achieves the exact layout of your second picture, but doesn't wrap items as window size changes. To do that you would probably need a custom Grid control that dynamically arranges children as container is resized.

Comment: That's what I considered in the past, but what I need is something that can resize when the window changes size. With grids (and uniform grids), I know you have specify the rows and columns in advance. I need something where I don't need to explicitly declare how many rows/cols I need. The only word I can describe this is the layout needs to be 'responsive'.

Comment: I guess you would need to create a custom panel control, which would internally use a Grid for child elements. Would be very tricky to pull off.

Comment: Not really what I want to do, but if that's what it comes to, then so be it.